# Can I let rainwater run along the wall?

Tags: drainage, rain

I have 2 concrete small slabs (2m x 5m) that are sloped with 1.5% ending in the wall of the lower floor, 3 sides of the slabs have walls (just the low level doesn't). What is the best course of action to deal with this rain water?

Can I just let it run along the wall below?

Should I build a small (10cm) wall in the open end and use a scupper or some other thing?

I don't want to use gutter because I will need to put a ladder against it from time to time for maintenance.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some context about where this is going? you mentioned a ladder - is it high up, or does it drain against a foundation wall?

Comment: I edited my post adding the full house in context. This slab will have a water tank above it and also will serve as a middle ground for a ladder getting on the top slab of the second floor.

Comment: And the water runs towards the open end with the door? i.e. it will run down that wall?

Comment: @Steven, this is one of the things I'm trying to avoid. But I'm not too concerned because I will probably put an awning above it to protect it from the rain regardless of the method of drainage.

Comment: Put up an eavestrough, and then put a bunch of these on the 2 story wall:  http://www.mec.ca/product/5005-789/metolius-50-hold-mega-pack/?f=10+50001+50058  No more ladders!  Fun and Functional!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the easiest solution would be to just put up a gutter and then move the lower ladder to one of the other walls, no?

[image]

Comment: From left to right, the one against the big wall could be used but I would rather not since I dont like the idea of moving sideways to the slab (and jumping the gutter); the one on the right wall I can't use because that is on my neighbor's side; the one on the back is doable, but the wall over there is much higher (my ladder doesn't reach it), about 4 m. This is why I have a problem, I must use the "open" side.

Comment: Agreed, you could even just use a ladder stabilizer so there is no contact with the gutter.

Comment: or use a shorter ladder so it rests below the gutter

Answer (score 1):

I would add a gutter and then use a ladder standoff

[image]

You can get standoffs that either bolt onto the ladder with U-bolts or which clip-onto the rungs and are held with a spring-clip

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could add some drip edge flashing, such as the one in the top right: 
[image]

This would help a bit, and not interfere with the ladder placement.

However, I really recommend putting a proper eaves trough and downspout.  This will keep water from pooling against the foundation, and running under the door.

If you really need a ladder space, run the trough over the door, and install drip edge over the 18 inches nearest the wall, so you can place the ladder.

(image source: http://www.easternwahomeinspections.com/drip-edge-flashing-on-your-home-is-recommended )